# What was the name of the Pharaoh during the time of Moses?

Tags: history, exodus, moses, ancient-egypt

In the Bible it never mentions Pharaoh's name but every other king/queen is mentioned by name. Did I miss it? What's his name?

Comment: Here's a pretty relevant Wikipedia page: [Pharaohs in the Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pharaohs_in_the_Bible)

Comment: Moses encountered several Pharoahs, which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 2):

Nobody knows for sure but modern speculations and depictions have centered on Ramses the II, Aka Ramses the Great.   Here is an Egyptian news paper article on the subject.

http://thecairopost.youm7.com/news/142273/culture/ramses-ii-pharaoh-of-exodus-researcher-says

"In the Bible it never mentions Pharaoh's name but every other king/queen is mentioned by name. Did I miss it? Whats his name?"

I believe that you are mixing up genres.   In the Later books of the Bible, the names of Kings, Pharaohs, and Emperors are named specifically.    In Genesis, however only The Canaanite Kings are named, and none of the Pharaohs that the patriarchs met are named.   So no it's not really surprising that the Pharaoh was not specifically named since that was not the custom of the original oral tradition of the time (That was eventually recorded by Moses).